# Is the boundary divisor of a smooth projective toric variety an snc divisor?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth toric projective variety.
Let $T$ be the big torus acting on $X$.
Let $D=X\backslash T$ be the boundary divisor.

Question 1. Will $D_i$ be a smooth toric projective variety for each irreducible component of $D$?

Question 2. Can we replace "smooth" by "normal" above?

P.S. Only over char=0 field.

Comment: Q1. Yes, as an affine toric variety $\operatorname{Spec} k[P]$ is smooth if and only if $P\simeq \mathbf{N}^r \times \mathbf{Z}^s$, and so it is easy to see that a smooth toric variety is locally of the form $X = \mathbf{A}^n$, $D=$ union of some coordinate hyperplaces. Q2. No, take a rational simplicial cone in $\mathbf{R}^3$ whose faces are not generated by their rays. I recommend consulting some basic reference on toric varieties, e.g. Fulton's book. (The characteristic zero assumption is irrelevant.)